# Bootstrap tabs broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small web application that uses twitter bootstrap tabs. Recently it has stopped working.

In investigating this, it appears the basic tabs on bootstraps own demo page don't work either. See: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

I've tested this in Firefox, Chrome and IE. On multiple machines. Bootstrap tabs are broken across the board.

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Works on my machine, are you sure you have javascript enabled?

Comment: Make sure you're not looking at the "Basic tabs", but rather at the "Tabbable example" which is an actual working example

Comment: Yup, you are abolutley correct. Jumped to conclusions because js wasn't loading and my application was behaving exactly the same way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tabs on the page you mention are just the visual elements; they don't have any logic to hide and display alternative tab content. For that you need javascript as illustrated on the [Javascript plugins](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) page.